# Text on an ActionBar Icon is not updating on new count

Tags: android, toolbar

am inflating menu item inside fragments `onCreateOptionsMenu()`.

Point 1 :
But here `onCreateOptionsMenu` is calling multiple time, am no where calling `invalidateOptionMenu()` inside fragment and am not getting why it is like this.

Point 2: 
I am updating cart count (badge count) please look my code below,
`mCartCountTextView` is member that hold the TextView,that holds count value. Am setting `mCartCountTextView` in some where of fragment by calling `refreshCartCount()`,but the value of `mCartCountTextView` is not updating even though `SharedPreference` has updated value.

Code Snippet:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);

    menu.clear();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_base, menu);
    MenuItem cartItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_cart);
    cartItem.setActionView(R.layout.base_menu_custom_layout);
    cartItem.getActionView().setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mMenuClickListener.onCartClick();
        }
    });
    mCartCountTextView = ((TextView) cartItem.getActionView().findViewById(R.id.cart_count));
    refreshCartCount();
}

public void refreshCartCount() {

    if (PreferenceManager.getInstance(getActivity()).getCustomerCartCount() == 0)
        mCartCountTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    else {
        mCartCountTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mCartCountTextView.setText(String.valueOf(PreferenceManager.getInstance(getActivity()).getCustomerCartCount()));
    }
}
```

How do I fix it?

Here am calling `invalidateOptionsMenu()` inside same fragment.

```
@Override
public void setCartResponse(CartListDTO response) {
    hideProgressBar();
    showToast(response.message);
    if (response.status == 1) {
        mCartBtn.setText(R.string.go_to_cart);
        getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
    }
}
```

Comment: Any answer or comment is highly appreciated. . . .

Comment: is PreferenceManager your local class?

Comment: yes,and value of getCustomerCartCount() is updated but textview is not showing it display prev. value..

Comment: `refreshCartCount()` will be called only once. right ? Are you able to get any value in `PreferenceManager.getInstance(getActivity()).getCustomerCartCount())`?

Comment: @SweetWisher:Yes, preferenc contains updated value always

Comment: do you call refreshCartCount anywhere else?

Comment: Put proper logs and see how the flow is working.

Comment: @ Pooya: am calling refreshCartCount whenever i add item to cart..

Comment: check if you are calling refresh() func before updating the preference

Comment: @SweetWisher ツ: i debugged flow is fine and it is comming to refreshcount.. but view count is not updating...

Comment: @Jayanth: no jayanth refresh is called only after preference update.

Comment: You'll require to call `invalidateOptionsMenu` in order to reflect the changes you made in menu item

Comment: @SweetWisher ツ: invalidateoptionMenu also i tried but same result...

Comment: show me your latest code

Comment: @ SweetWisher ツ: i updated code..

Comment: what is `mCartBtn` and what is `mCartCountTextView`? in `setCartResponse` you're updating mCartBtn.

Comment: mCartButton is different , mCartCountTextView is count view that updates value

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111613/discussion-between-sweetwisher--and-ram).

Comment: did you tried to use supportInvalidateOptionsMenu?

Comment: @visionix visionix:yes no use..