# Is fragment backstack entry count will impact onCreateOptionmenu() invoke?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-toolbar

What exactly i mean is, say if `backstack entry` count of `FragmentManager` is 2 
then current fragments `onCreateOptionmenu()`  is calling twice,
if count is 3 then `onCreateOptionmenu()` calling thrice and so on...

Is this bug or natural?

Because am facing problem because of multiple call to `onCreateOptionmenu()`..

Comment: if you nest two fragments they both call onCreateOptionsMenu when being created, that is when they are being called upon, so its by design. but they can never be called in the background.

Comment: No,i made setHasOptionmenu(false) in second fragment(nested child fragment)

Comment: Do you suggest that fragments which not in the back stack can't inflate menu?

Comment: No not like that, it will inflate.But backstack count increase onCreateOptionsMenu will invoke that many count time.

because of this multiple invoke am facing this problem please refer-->
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37134559/text-on-an-actionbar-icon-is-not-updating-on-new-count?noredirect=1#comment61855021_37134559

Comment: With supported fragments cannot reproduce your problem. Simplify code, isolate problem and post it here.

Comment: i din't get your comment "With supported fragments"..

Comment: Fragments from [supported library](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html)

Comment: Ya am using android.support.v4.app.Fragment; only..

Answer (score 0):

Why do you referring to the back stack?

This the job of fragment manager. When fragment attached and has setHasOptionsMenu(true) fragment manager will call onCreateOptionsMenu.

Possible issue - you added the same fragment twice.

Comment: Am using separate toolbar for fragment ( collapsing toolbar with parallax effect)  and each time created fragment using replaceAndAddFragment..

Am inflating menu item inside fragments
 public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) not host activity onCreateOptionsMenu.